# Determine the length of a generic type?

Tags: vb.net, generics, struct, size

How can I at run-time determine the length of a generic type (with constraint Structure).

I need the byte count to create a view accessor of a MemoryMappedFile (which is initialized in the constructor).

```
Private goVirtualFile As MemoryMappedFile
Private glLength As Long = 0            

Public Class CTest(Of T As Structure)
    Public Sub Append(tData As T())
        Dim iNumStruct As Integer = tData.Length         'Number of structures.
        Dim iStructLen As Integer = ...                  'Length of 1 structure in bytes.
        Dim iBytes As Integer = iNumStruct * iStructLen  'Total length in bytes.

        Using goViewStream = goVirtualFile.CreateViewAccessor(
            glLength, iBytes)
            ...
        End Using
    End Sub

    Public Function Read(lOffset As Long, iNumStruct As Integer) As T()
        ...
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Assuming `T` has a fixed size, you might use [Marshal.SizeOf Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.sizeof(v=vs.110).aspx).  However, it really depends on your end goal.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: As @TnTinMn said, `Marshal.SizeOf()` is the usual way. So your field would be `Dim iStructLen As Integer = Marshal.SizeOf(tData(0))`. You also need some kind fail-safe check there, before `iNumStruct` is calculated.

Comment: @TnTinMn, I updated my question with relevant information.

Comment: @TnTinMn Well, when the actual structure is passed to the Append method, it's not generic anymore.

Comment: The framework already needs to solve this problem, [code is here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/unmanagedmemoryaccessor.cs,559).

Comment: @TnTinMn, and what about functions returning T() (see modified question).

Comment: @Herb, I am a bit hesitant to recommend using the Marshal Class methods because you are using a MemoryMappedFile that could imply communication between processes.  Those processes could be 32 bit or 64 bit and the resultant record size returned from Marshal.SizeOf  could be influenced by bitness.  Personally, I would require the structure to interpret/generate a Byte array of predetermined size.  Again, it all hinges your usage case.

Comment: @TnTinMn, no inter-communication processes involved. If you bother to aggregate your comments into an answer, I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Herb, After following the code paths in in the link provided by Hans, I can not in good faith recommend using `Marshal.SizeOf` for the computing size of the ViewAccessor size because it appears that there are other size determining methods (`Marshal.AlignedSizeOf<T>` is one) used when reading and writing records that are not publicly exposed by the API.  Not knowing how those methods may differ from `Marshal.SizeOf` makes impossible to say that the computed accessor length will be correct.  In my opinion, answer is that what you want to do is not possible.